# Define properties for object instances

Tags: python, properties

Given an object `foo` (to which i have access) of class `A` (to which i have no access).

`foo` has an attribute *x*, which is accessed by alot of parties which can also set `foo.x`.

Is it somehow possible to replace `foo.x` with a `@property`-like such that assignments like

```
foo.x = "bar"
```

Will from then on invoke a function specified by me? If so, is it also possible to remove this property afterwards and replace it with something like e.g `foo.x = "not a property"` again?

Please consider: I have no access to the class but only to the object.

Comment: Well, you have access to the call when you have the object: `your_object.__class__`.

Comment: @KlausD. It's not that much about whether I could access the class, but whether I actually want to. I hoped to find some alternative way here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put properties on an instance, no. You'll have to monkey-patch the class, or subclass it.

Monkey-patching would require you to store the original attribute somewhere on the instance still, using a different name:

```
def getter(self):
    try:
        return self._x
    except AttributeError:
        # access the attribute on the instance directly.
        try:
            return self.__dict__['x']
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError('x')

def setter(self, value):
    self._x = value

foo._x = foo.x
type(foo).x = property(getter, setter)
```

This sets the `property` object on the class. Now *all* instances of that class will have that property! To deal with this, the getter above falls back to trying to get the original `x` attribute value from the instance `__dict__` if no `_x` attribute is present. This should ensure that existing instances continue to work.

Removing the property is as simple as deleting it:

```
del type(foo).x
```

Note that this *will* conflict with a *class* attribute (e.g. if `type(foo).x` is an existing object).